# Selecting both empty and non-empty cells

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a dynamically created table (via AJAX), and I have an event that needs to happen upon clicking on a cell:

The problem is that the table is populated with Datatables, and after loading the table with json, the cell contains either an empty `span` or a `span` with text:

```
<td> <span class="editnote"></span> </td>

<td> <span class="editnote">Non-empty cell</span> </td>
```

I cannot move the class to the `<td>`, because it is created by Datatables.

How can I select with jQuery (or via Javascript) the specific `span` that was clicked upon.

At first, I set the css `.editnote {min-width:25px;}` because I thought it was zero width (and thus unclickable).  This did not work.

I am able to select both empty and non-empty cells:

Non-empty cells:

```
$('tbody').click(function(e){
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('editnote')){
    //... do stuff ...
  }
});
```

Empty cells:

```
$('tbody').click(function(e){
  if ($(e.target).find('span').hasClass('editnote')){
    //... do stuff ...
  }
});
```

Is there a way to select both cells with one statement?

Comment: Something like `$(e.target).closest('td').find('.editnote')`?

Comment: Wow, that is why I love StackOverflow.  That works great, @Karl-AndréGagnon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function () {
     var td = $(this);
     var editNoteSpan = td.find('span.editnote');

     if(editNoteSpan.length > 0) {
         alert('success');
     }
});
```

Comment: As is, this does not work, but changing `td.editnote` to `td>span.editnote` works only on the cells that are not empty.

Comment: oh im sorry I forgot you had a span in there. ill correct my code right now

Comment: That is because you are going to have some trouble with having the spans being of size 0x0 since there is no content in them. One more edit coming your way!

Comment: Actually, works on my site too.  This is actually better than ` $(e.target).closest('td').find('.editnote')` in the above comments, because it doesn't affect other `td`.  Thank you!

Comment: this utilizes jQuery delegate, which I originally accidentally commented on another answer and I noticed you were asking about it. A little google search and you should come across this link here: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/  Enjoy! and KEEP ON CODING! :)

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon.  It also grabs other `td`'s.  It does in your codepen too  :(

Comment: you can fix that by varying your selectors a little bit. I would need to see more of your source in order to help you out with that. Is it on a public URL somewhere that I can view it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66520/discussion-between-stephenkelzer-and-sable-foste).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function () {
  var $td = $(this);
  if ($td.find('.editnote').length > 0) {
    /* This <td> does have an .editnote element... */
  }
});
```

Maybe?

Comment: It has to be target based, since the data doesn't exist in when loaded.

Comment: This will work too. It checks the target to see if it's a `<td>`. This basically checks if `event.target` is a `<td>`, assigns the `this` to the target and goes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me.  I tried with both text and no text, and it just seems to do nothing (I added an alert).  I would be interested to see if you could point to how this uses the delegate function.  I am currently using jQuery 1.7.2.

Comment: The `.delegate()` function is very similar. Just swap 'click' and 'td' and use `.delegate` instead of `.on`.

Comment: How my answer didn't work and the accepted one did is a bit confusing since it's the same code. ;p

Comment: The second if statement in the accepted answer was critical.  Otherwise, all cells (not just the ones with the editnote class) would return the action.

Comment: Not sure what second if you're talking about, but no big deal. Have fun!